# How to do I rename a file using data found within it?

Tags: perl

I know this has been asked before, and I've done my research and I think my problem is I'm using a symbolic reference?  However, I don't think those dangers apply here and to be honest, I don't understand the alternative methods I've looked up.
I create a list of files using glob.  I then open each one, find the name which is always $split_line[3] and then I want to rename the file "$split_line[3]-stock.txt"

The code I have is:

```
my @eng_stock_file = glob ('./CRM/*.txt'); 
foreach my $file (@eng_stock_file) {
    chomp $file;
    open (CRM_FILE, '<', $file) or die ("Can't open $file\n");
    while (my $line = <CRM_FILE>) {
        if ($line !~ m/^\(Do Not Modify\)/) {
            my @split_line = split("\t", $line);
            my $engineer = $split_line[3];
            #print $engineer;
            close ($file);
            last;
        }
        my $new_file = "$engineer-stock.txt";
        #print $new_file;
        move ($file, $new_file) or die "Couldn't rename the stock file.\n";
    }
}
```

It's the attempted creation of $new_file that doesn't work and I'd very much appreciate some help with it.  Thanks.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256881/discussion-on-question-by-pete-g-how-to-do-i-rename-a-file-using-data-found-with); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Problems with your original code:

- Scope: `$engineer` was out of scope when it was used to build `$new_file`.
- You haven't closed `CRM_FILE` before renaming it. That's a problem in Windows.
- You used the `move` function (nonexisting) instead of the `rename` function.

To learn about similar problems in the future early, start your Perl script with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`, and fix each error and warning reported by Perl.

The code with the fixes:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @eng_stock_file = glob ('./CRM/*.txt'); 
foreach my $file (@eng_stock_file) {
    #chomp $file;  # Not needed, there is no newline at the end of your filename.
    my $CRM_FILE;
    open ($CRM_FILE, '<', $file) or die ("Can't open $file\n");
    my $new_file;
    while (my $line = <$CRM_FILE>) {
        if ($line !~ m/^\(Do Not Modify\)/) {
            my @split_line = split("\t", $line);
            my $engineer = $split_line[3];
            #print $engineer;
            $new_file = "$engineer-stock.txt";
            last;
        }
    }
    close ($CRM_FILE);
    die "Missing new filename.\n" if !defined($new_file); 
    #print $new_file;
    rename($file, $new_file) or die "Couldn't rename the stock file from $file to $new_file: $!\n";
}
```

Comment: This works without errors.  It has the effect of deleting the files I want renaming.  I appreciate this is difficult to reproduce so I will spend some time working with your modified code.  Much appreciate the help.  I'm a lot closer to getting it working now.

Comment: Looks like what they may need,  but note from `perldoc rename` -- "_Behavior of this function varies wildly depending on your system implementation. [...] For a platform independent "move" function look at the File::Copy module._"

Comment: Happy doing it any way.  That last rename command is literally all I want to achieve!  Going to have to leave it for now.  Will pick up tomorrow.  I'm using Strawberry Perl for Windows btw.

Answer (score 3):

- Declare `$engineer` before the loop
- Assign it inside the loop (if you find a matching line)
- Check if it's `defined` after the loop.

Other notes:

- Don't `chomp` the filename. If that succeeds, it means that the file had a newline in its name and then opening the file will fail.
- `close` the file descriptor, not `$file`.

Example:

```perl
my @eng_stock_file = glob ('./*.txt');
foreach my $file (@eng_stock_file) {
    my $engineer;
    print "trying $file\n";
    open (my $CRM_FILE, $file) or die ("$file: $!\n");
    while (my $line = <$CRM_FILE>) {
        if ($line !~ m/^\(Do Not Modify\)/) {
            my @split_line = split("\t", $line);

            # check that the split results in at least four elements:
            next unless(@split_line > 3);

            # assignment only: 
            $engineer = $split_line[3];
            last;
        }
    }
    # close the file descriptor:
    close ($CRM_FILE);

    # check that engineer was assigned a value:
    if(defined $engineer) {
        my $new_file = "$engineer-stock.txt";
        print "moving $file to $new_file\n";

        # Uncomment this when if you are happy with what's printed above
        #move ($file, $new_file) or die "Couldn't rename the stock file.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like what they may be asking.  For sanity, I'd turn around that negated condition and write `next if $line =~ /^\(Do Not Modify\)/;` and then have the rest of the code straight (no conditions needed).  They should clarify that `last`, too -- does the very first line which isn't `Do Not Modify` have the engineer?

Comment: @zdim Yeah and perhaps `^\(Do Not Modify\)` anywhere in the file actually means _"do not move the file"_. In that case the whole file would need to be checked for that tag before renaming it.

Comment: "_actually means_"  -- yeah, quite a bit of the logic isn't clear to me